# In Titanic,Why does Old Rose throw the diamond in the sea

Tags: titanic

In the End, Rose throws off the Heart of Ocean in the Sea.There are numerous theories trying to find out the real reason.

1).The fact that it didn’t belong to her anyways.So it would be unethical to keep it.

2)She was gonna die anyways

3)She threw it to complete a "Life Circle".Gave something to where it all began.

Any other strong reasoning why she let it go?

**Edit:**
The other question is similar, but does not cover all possible reasons.I have mentioned the answer there in above bullet points

Comment: Because she's an awful person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Beginning, Cal to Rose: OPEN your Heart to me Rose.

Immediate action by Rose She puts her hand on the Heart of Ocean blocking/CLOSING it.

At the end of the film, old Rose luckily manages to go back right above Titanic's wreck where she saw Jack the last time and lets the Heart of the Ocean go,

As a sign of OPENING her heart to Jack and his memory.

Credit: